# Cannot Create Test Complete Object in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testcomplete

I am new to Visual Studio / Test Complete / C#.  I have written a Test Complete test in C#,  but when I try to run it it says "Cannot Create Test Complete Object".  The only question so far that I have found does not apply to me.  Even if it did, I did, as it suggested, run the program as admin but the same problem.

This is nowhere near enough information for you to go on, so let me continue.

My Test Complete test extends a class "AbstractTestCase" that we got from our team.  This is the base class that has been used for years, so I am sure it is OK.  I made a simple test, just to try to click an object.  I have no idea whether the values are correct, but for now it does not matter, as my test is throwing an exception in the "Before()" method, so it has not gotten there yet.

The exception is being thrown at this method, which I believe is Smart Bear method, so I cannot debug into it, and it shows no line number:

```
Connect.RunTest(GetTestName(), "Generic", Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Automation\TcFramwork\TcFramwork.pjs");
```

The values are as follows:

GetTestName() =  "RepriceTest"

Path.GetDirectoryName...  =  "C:\VS_Projects\ErepricerSolution\ErepriceClassLibrary\bin\Debug\Automation\TcFramwork\TcFramwork.pjs"

I do have a file  C:\VS_Projects\ErepricerSolution\ErepriceClassLibrary\bin\Debug\Automation\TcFramwork\TcFramwork.pjs

which looks like this (along with a "Generic" subdirectory).  Please see attached file. To attach it I had to convert it to an XML file.

The only difference is this.  Because my Desktop started crashing, I was one of the first (and only so far) people to get a laptop.  Others will be getting themn as time goes on.  The laptop has Windows 10, while everyone else has Windows 7.  The Laptop has Test Complete 12.  The laptop had Visual Studio 2015, but due to compiler incompatibilities with Smart Bear Connetc, I had to have Visual Studio 12 installed, which I am using.

So others are using Windows 7, Visual Studio 12 and Test complete 12, while I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 12 and Test Complete 12.

I do see somewhat of a backtrace from this Connect.RunTest(), so maybe someone can figure out what's going on.  Please see attached file trace.png.

I am also attaching a copy of my test class. (And again I have no idea whether the Connect statement is right, but it never gets that far)

I can't upload files but I did share them on my google drive.

PJS file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FZ2__0smKTKZ8d6mqVxIO8gP4r_A-92y

```
 Test Class: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ixitvZ45M11Va1eDv-7Vv9Lz9WHh-k41

 Stack Trace: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C57iNacRnrmmGkE4Lx9mvetobPiJN3G4

 PSJ File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FZ2__0smKTKZ8d6mqVxIO8gP4r_A-92y
```

Comment: I guess that the problem is that the TestComplete COM object cannot be accessed. Try running this code that does this directly:

const string TCProgID = "TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication.14";

object TestCompleteObject = null;

try
{
    TestCompleteObject = Marshal.GetActiveObject(TCProgID);
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        TestCompleteObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(TCProgID));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

Comment: Sorry.  I was away at a funeral and just got back.  I saw this.  I will try it but it looks like you need Test Complete 14 for that?  I tried finding Marshal before but could not find it.  I will try your example with the id both as 14 and 12 and see whether it will work.  But I think it will not be able to find Marshal.

Comment: OK I added "     ".  With TestComplete.TestCompleteApplication.14 I get exceptions (after adding some debugging) "Invalid Class String at Marshal.CLSIDFromProgID(String progId, Guid& clsid).  When I change it from 14 to 12, I get "Operation unavailable" from Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid &rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)

Comment: Are you running your application as an Admin? Also, try disabling the "[Enable support for testing Windows Store applications (requires restart)](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/options/engines/general.html)" option in TestComplete.

Comment: Didn't see this.  Yes, disabling Windows Store support worked.  I answered a few times on the Smart Bear page.  Anyway, I tried both with and without running as admin and it seems to work now,, so not sure I need admin but I do need to disable the store applications.